# Encode Data Matrix on Android

Tags: android, matrix

Is there any open source (and non-GPL) Data Matrix encoder available for Android? I could find only commercial ones. And on Stack Overflow I didn't find any answer to this question.

Comment: Are you really restricted to Datamatrix format? Because using QR Codes would prove much easier...

Comment: Yep, I know. But I certainly need data matrix codes.